# How to convert a choice type automatically provided by XmlProvider<...>.DomainTypes into an enumeration in F#?

Tags: xml, f#, enumeration, type-providers, f#-data

Let's say I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<iAmConfused>
    <helpMe feeling="anger" strength="100" mapping="1-1" />
    <helpMe feeling="frustration" strength="15" mapping="1-n" />
    <helpMe feeling="helplessness" strength="365" mapping="1-1" />
    <helpMe feeling="despair" strength="-1" mapping="1-n" />
</iAmConfused>
```

And want to transform it to an F# Map:

```
open System.Xml
open System.Xml.Linq
open FSharp.Data

type mappingType =
    | oneToOneMapping = 00
    | oneToManyMapping = 01

type helpMe = {
    strength : int;
    mapping : mappingType}

type iAmConfusedXmlType = XmlProvider<"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><iAmConfused><helpMe feeling="anger" strength="100" mapping="1-1" /><helpMe feeling="frustration" strength="15" mapping="1-n" /><helpMe feeling="helplessness" strength="365" mapping="1-1" /><helpMe feeling="despair" strength="-1" mapping="1-n" /></iAmConfused>""">

let iAmConfusedXml = iAmConfusedXmlType.Parse("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><iAmConfused><helpMe feeling="anger" strength="100" mapping="1-1" /><helpMe feeling="frustration" strength="15" mapping="1-n" /><helpMe feeling="helplessness" strength="365" mapping="1-1" /><helpMe feeling="despair" strength="-1" mapping="1-n" /></iAmConfused>""")

let iWantThisMap =
    iAmConfusedXml.GetHelpMes()
    |> Seq.map (fun e -> e.Feeling, {
        strength = e.Strength;
        mapping = ???})
    |> Map.ofSeq
```

`XmlProvider` correctly infers the type of XML attribute `mapping` to be `XmlProvider<...>.DomainTypes.MappingChoice`. However, I can't find a way to convert this type to `mappingType`.

First I tried to convert XML attribute `mapping` to string in the hopes of then converting it to enumeration `mappingType`, but even that proves to be too difficult for me...

Rewriting type helpMe in the above code:

```
type helpMe = {
    strength : int;
    mapping : string}
```

Then substituting `???` to

```
string e.Strength
```

Gives me `"Some(1-1)"` or `"Some(1-n)"` for `helpMe.mapping` which is not what I want.
If I try to substitute `???` to

```
string (defaultArg e.Mapping "")
```

Then FSI rightfully complains:

```
test.fs(165,38): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'a option    
but here has type
    XmlProvider<...>.DomainTypes.MappingChoice
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to convert from a string to `mappingType`, you can define a little helper function:

```
let convert m =
    match m with
    | "1-1" -> mappingType.oneToOneMapping
    | _ -> mappingType.oneToManyMapping
```

Which will enable you to write your projection like:

```
let iWantThisMap =
    iAmConfusedXml.GetHelpMes()
    |> Seq.map (fun e -> e.Feeling, {
        strength = e.Strength;
        mapping = (e.Mapping.Value |> convert) })
    |> Map.ofSeq
```

Now, there's a bit of cheating here because it's simply calling `e.Mapping.Value`. This might throw an exception if `e.Mapping` is `None`, but it works given the data provided here, because `e.Mapping` always has a value.